# Unity avoiding obstacles with pathfinding c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, raycasting

I have a simple project which includes pathfinding with obstacle avoidance. Now, I have `void Steer` which steers the object around since the path is not straight. then I have `void AvoidObstacles` which has raycast and the obstacle avoidance part basically.

Whenever the object steers, it calls the `AvoidObstacles` function. The problem now is, at the start, whenever it hasn't call in the `Steer` function yet, because it is a straigh line, it passes through the object not avoiding it.

Here are some of the codes used:

```
 public Vector3 Steer(Vector3 target, bool bFinalPoint = false)
 {
    //Calculate the directional vector from the current position towards the target point
    Vector3 desiredVelocity = (target - transform.position);
    float dist = desiredVelocity.magnitude;



    AvoidObstacles(ref desiredVelocity);
    //Normalise the desired Velocity
    desiredVelocity.Normalize();

    //Calculate the velocity according to the speed
    if (bFinalPoint && dist < 10.0f)
        desiredVelocity *= (curSpeed * (dist / 10.0f));
    else 
        desiredVelocity *= curSpeed;

    //Calculate the force Vector
    Vector3 steeringForce = desiredVelocity - velocity; 
    Vector3 acceleration = steeringForce / mass;

    return acceleration;
}
```

here is the other one

```
public void AvoidObstacles(ref Vector3 desiredVelocity)
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 leftRay = transform.position;
    Vector3 rightRay = transform.position;

    //leftRay.x -= 2;
    //rightRay.x += 2;

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position,(transform.forward * 5) + transform.position,Color.green);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward,out hit, minimumDistToAvoid))
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position,(transform.forward * 10) + transform.position,Color.red);
        if(hit.transform != transform)
        {
           //dir += hit.normal * 50;
           //Get the normal of the hit point to calculate the new direction
           Vector3 hitNormal = hit.normal;
           hitNormal.y = 0.0f; //Don't want to move in Y-Space

           //Get the new directional vector by adding force to vehicle's current forward vector
           desiredVelocity = transform.forward + hitNormal * force;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my update

```
    void Update () 
{
    //Unify the speed
    curSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    targetPoint = path.GetPoint(curPathIndex);

    //If reach the radius within the path then move to next point in the path
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPoint) < path.Radius)
    {
        //Don't move the vehicle if path is finished 
        if (curPathIndex < pathLength - 1)
            curPathIndex ++;
        else if (isLooping)
            curPathIndex = 0;
        else
            return;
    }

    //Move the vehicle until the end point is reached in the path
    if (curPathIndex >= pathLength )
        return;

    //Calculate the next Velocity towards the path
    if(curPathIndex >= pathLength - 1 && !isLooping)
        velocity += Steer(targetPoint, true);
    else
        velocity += Steer(targetPoint);

    transform.position += velocity; //Move the vehicle according to the velocity
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(velocity); //Rotate the vehicle towards the desired Velocity
    //AvoidObstacles(ref Vector3 desiredVelocity);
    dir.Normalize();
}
```

Maybe someone can help me out buy letting me know how can I call the avoidobstacle function outside of steer? Maybe in update or start perhaps.
I can't really use other algorithms, just this one right here. TIA

Comment: Wouldn't manually calling the `Steer` function manually just after instanciating the objects involved be an option ?

Comment: posted my update code. and no, i dont think it will work that way @PhilGref